# Unexpected behavior with ArrayList.remove()

Tags: java, android, arraylist

I have a pizza code that iterates through a list of objects and checks whether they are colliding or not.  If one is collided with, it is removed from the ArrayList.

```
for (int i = 0; i < arrayList.size(); i++) {
    Object c = arrayList.get(i);
    if (Rect.intersects(foo.getRect(), c.getRect())) { //Android function, checks if the two rectangles are inside each other.
        foo.setPosY(c.getPosY() + 11); // Always works.
        foo.setVelY(bird.getVelY() * -1); // Always works.
        arrayList.remove(i); // Occasionally fails under special circumcisions.
    }
}
```

When opening the app fresh for the first time this works fine.  However, if I exit with the back button and then quickly reopen the app, it will all work *except* occasionally, removing the object from the ArrayList wont happen.

If I close the app and then remove it from the recent apps list, it works.  If I exit with the home key, or the back button and then immediately reopen, it sometimes fails to remove the object.  I don't understand why this happens, as everything else still works.  The two lines of code just before it function just fine.  I just don't get it.

Comment: How can this code work? `c` is declared as an `Object` and `Object` has no `.get*()` methods... Or is this something else than `java.lang.Object`?

Comment: Firstly, you're always skipping an element after you remove one. Either work from back to front, or decrement `i` after a `remove` operation, or use an iterator.

Comment: @fge, Sorry.  I meant for that to imply a custom class of mine.  It's just a foo object that has a rect that you can get.

Comment: @JonSkeet: does remove() method put null at that position or entirely remove it from list??

Comment: @RipalTamboli: It removes it completely from the list, and later elements are moved up.

Comment: `.remove()` will remove from the list

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I suspect the problem is that you're skipping an element after one call to remove, because you're incrementing `i` *and* everything in the list is moving up one element. (It's not really clear what the symptoms are at the moment. If this turns out not to be *the* problem, it's still *a* problem.)

So if you call `remove(2)`, the next element you want to look at now has index 2.

Common ways of fixing this:

- Work backwards:

  ```
  for (int i = arrayList.size() - 1; i >= 0; i--)
  ```
- Use an iterator instead:

  ```
  for (Iterator<Foo> iterator = arrayList.iterator(); iterator.hasNext(); ) {
      Foo c = iterator.next();
      if (...) {
          iterator.remove();
      }
  }
  ```

Comment: Wow, thanks.  I can't believe how long I've overlooked that.  I've fixed that issue and tested it.  Unfortunately the problem still persists.  I am thankful for you pointing that out though.  I will be more mindful in the future.

Comment: @user3321627: If the problem still persists, you should edit your question to give more diagnostic information. `ArrayList.remove()` definitely *do* work, so I suggest you log the contents before and after the `remove()` call...

Comment: @Skeet, yes, it does 100% work as long as it's not in the recent list.  I cannot get it to show this behavior on a fresh start.  I've tried 100+ times.  It will only do it after it's been ran, and it will do it often at the point, but not every time.    I've tried using debug mode, and it will show the same behavior but only while actually running.  It will not do it while I'm stepping through.

Comment: @Jimicrackcorn: Then add logging anyway, and look at the log after it's failed.

Comment: thank you.  I will try to figure out how to do that.

Comment: @skeet Alright, I logged the sizes.  The size of the array on a fresh boot is 28.  It's doubles in size each successive start up.  I can only assume that I need to nullify the array before I initialize it each time.  Upon doing so the array does not double in size and I have to guess the issue is gone.  Thank you for your help.